# how to parse the json file and read the json elements in groovy

Tags: json, groovy

Hi i am trying to parse the below json file.  I tried using jsonsluper and parsed the file. I executed below command.  Nothing works.

```
def test =newjsonslurper().parsetext(organist)
  test.resources.each{
  println it.resources.metadata. "guid"
  println it.resources.entity. "name"
}
```

This is the json file format

```
resources: [
  {
    "metadata" :{
    "guid":"cya"
     "url": "dummy.test"
  },
  "entity" :
    {
      "name": "system"
      "status": "active"
    }
  }
  {
    "metadata" :
       {
         "guid":"cya"
         "url": "dummy.test"
       },
     "entity" :
       {
         "name": "system"
         "status": "active"
       }
  }
]
```

Comment: Your json is a bracket and a comma.

Comment: that inner `resources` in the `each` is wrong in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a couple of problems:

- `JsonSlurper().parseText()` expects a String. If you're wanting to parse a file, use something like `def response = new JsonSlurper().parse(new File('JsonFile.json'))`
- The JSON payload is not valid: it's missing a few brackets and commas.

The following code should work:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def test = new JsonSlurper().parseText '''
{"resources": [
    {
        "metadata": {
            "guid": "cya",
            "url": "dummy.test"
        },
        "entity": {
            "name": "system",
            "status": "active"
        }
    },
    {
        "metadata": {
            "guid": "cya",
            "url": "dummy.test"
        },
        "entity": {
            "name": "system",
            "status": "active"
        }
    }
]}
'''

test.resources.each {
    println it.metadata.guid
    println it.entity.name
}
```

Comment: Hi, I can able to print the values but instead of printing the values I want to export to excel sheet, Please advise.

Comment: It depends on how complex your data model is and the quality of your data. A quick-and-dirty way of turning a couple of fields into a CSV would be `println it.metadata.guid + ',' + it.entity.name`.